# issue in fullscreen toggle in e4 applications (only mac)

Tags: java, macos, swt, e4

in my application i have an part sash which divides main view and detailed view

main view width = 300 and detail view width = 300

1. let say only the main view is visible in start up
2. you click on fullscreen button - which make your app goes to fullscreen mode
3. clicking on a button or something , the details view (right part) will open
4. clicking on the exit fullscreen
5. makes my application size 300 not 600

if you open the details view first and make the full-screen and exit the full-screen the app width is 600

what ever size of app before going to full-screen  , the same width is set once you exit from full screen

i am not able to set the width of window programmatically after exiting the full screen

i have tried `window.setWidth()` - doesn't work

Does someone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is this the Mac only full screen button (at the right of the title bar) that moves the app to a separate 'Space'?

Comment: yes this moves to the separate 'space'!!! (by clicking the right top button of the title bar)

Comment: i tried doing the resize of the app in 

shell_1.addListener(SWT.Resize,new Listener()

it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to delay running your code to set the window size until after the asynchronous code queued by the e4 `WBWRender` class has run.

As there does not seem to be a suitable event to use you could just schedule a UIJob to run a bit later:

```
UIJob job = new UIJob("set size")
   {
     @Override
     public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor monitor)
     {
       window.setWidth(800);

       return Status.OK_STATUS;
     }
  };

job.schedule(2000);
```

Two seconds seems about the shortest that works for me - all a bit of a bodge really!

Comment: i did the same thing , that works
but the user can see the delay in resizing 
is there any other way ?